# Accessing an aliased computed property from an Ember component

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am passing the value of an "Ember.computed.alias()" to a component via an attribute called "disabled". The alias itself points to a computed property.

Within the controller the alias carries the correct value returned by the computed property.  However, when I try to access the "disabled" attribute from within the component like this:

```
this.getAttr('disabled')
```

the value is always "undefined".

Should I be able to pass aliases of computed properties to components?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `this.get('disabled')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't make a difference.  I read a post by one of the Ember core team members recently saying that we should be using this.getAttr('attrName') or this.attr.attrName in components going forward to Ember 2.0 so I would have expected these to work.

Comment: What version of ember are you on now?

Comment: Ember 1.13.5 but I'm trying to future-proof my code. :-)

Comment: Are you saying `this.get("disabled")` isn't working either? If so then you might be setting or passing the property wrong. I think passing aliased properties should work just fine. Or maybe your "this" is nested inside a context other than the component? (like in a jQuery callback or something?)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My "this" is in the correct context so that can be ruled out. The "disabled" attribute is being passed correctly as I'm doing it the same way as other attributes that are visible in the component. I can only think that the alias of a computed property aspect is the issue but maybe somone else has another suggestion?

Comment: The computed property is not the problem, see this [JSBin here.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gawogeqofa/edit?html,js,console,output) A property is computed in TopComponent, and then passed to MiddleComponent where it gets aliased, and then the alias gets passed to BottomComponent. In BottomComponent, it still retains the same value.

Comment: If you could reproduce your issue in a JSBin or post some of the surrounding code then it would help us get to the problem.

Comment: Can you please post the template where you are using the component and passing in the aliased property?

Comment: The JS Bin you've created is similar to my problem but not quite the same as I am passing my properties from a controller to a component rather than between components.  I've modified it [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dicumegiqu/1/edit?html,js,console,output) but now I can't even get the "testProperty" value to be anything other than "undefined" so I've obviously done something wrong.

Comment: You're setting the `testData` property wrong in the controller, see this [updated JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/quzukazaro/edit?html,js,console,output) with some edits and added notes on setting computed properties.

Comment: That's weird. It looks like my js bin didn't save properly as it was missing most of the stuff I wrote & had the alias definition half finished. Thanks for your help with this.